# Problem adding code folding button in blogdown + Anatole theme

Tags: javascript, r, hugo, blogdown

I am having a problem adding code folding to Anatole theme in Blogdown.
I have followed [this blogpost](https://statnmap.com/2017-11-13-enable-code-folding-in-bookdown-and-blogdown/) and I managed to add both "Show/Hide all code" and the individual buttons for each code chunk.

The buttons above each code chunk work well but the "Show/Hide all code" button does not.

Here is a post with code in my blog: https://martinolmos.github.io/datos_tic/en/post/2021-11-09-30-day-map-challenge-day-3-and-4/

A funny thing I've noticed: when I inspect the button with developer tools and click in `event` this is what I see:

[image]

So, I think that for some reason when I click in the "Show/Hide all code" button it is calling `dropdown.js` twice and maybe the second call suppresses the first call. Could this be the problem? What can I do to fix it?

I don't know a lot of html/javascript so I apologize if this is a very basic/dumb question.

Comment: Look like you solved it, right?

Comment: Well, I still need to figure out how to fix it. Any clues?

Comment: Works for me in FF and Chrome.

Comment: I've added the link to the blog so you can see it for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right... you are embedding the footer `<footer>` twice, which adds the events twice. You can view this by looking at the page source in your browser. The first footer is loaded before the header (inside the sidebar). The second one at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Fixed. I moved `footer_js.html` from `footer.html` to the `<div class="post_footer">` in `single.html`.